# Partitioning the Projective Plane

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, projective-geometry

Throughout this post, by *projective plane* I mean the set of all lines through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

**Side Note:** If there are more standard definitions for any of the ideas presented here, please let me know.

**Definition:** Say that a subset $S$ of the projective plane is *octahedral* if all lines in $S$ pass through the closure of two opposite faces of a regular octahedron centered at the origin.

**Definition:** Say that a subset $S$ of the projective plane is *weakly octahedral* if every set $S'\subseteq S$ such that $|S'|=3$ is octahedral.

**Equivalent Definition:** Say that a subset $S$ of the projective plane is *weakly octahedral* if for any three lines in $S$ and any three vectors $x, y$ and $z$ which span these lines, we have
$$\langle x,y\rangle \cdot\langle x,z\rangle \cdot\langle y,z\rangle \geq 0$$
where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard (dot) inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Now, here is my question.

**Question:** Suppose that the projective plane can be partitioned into four sets, say $S_1,S_2,S_3$ and $S_4$ such that each set $S_i$ is weakly octahedral. Then is it necessarily true that each $S_i$ is octahedral?

**Note:** The fact that $S_1,S_2,S_3$ and $S_4$ partition the projective plane seems to be important. I believe that this is an example of a weakly octahedral set that is not octahedral: Fix any vector $x$ and let $S$ be the set of all lines which are spanned by vectors which meet $x$ at an angle strictly less than $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

This question came up while I was working on a graph colouring problem where the vertex set is the projective plane. For the specific problem, follow this link: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/?q=op/circular_colouring_the_orthogonality_graph

I've also posted the problem to the Open Problem Garden, as the answer seems to be unknown: http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/partitioning_the_projective_plane

Comment: Ifyou are right about S not being octahedral, why not make it one of the four parts of a weakly octahedral partitioning?

Comment: And how would you define the other three parts? :)

Comment: Start with an octahedral partition, and pick a central line l from one of them (like (1,1,1) is for the positive orthant).  Then use l to define S, taking away lines from the other three parts and putting them in S.

Comment: My imagery assumes S is a superset of one of the parts.  If S is not, then something else is needed.

Comment: @TMA I don't think that this works. The angle between (1,1,1) and (1,0,0) is more than pi/4. Moreover, if you modify the set S from above to use an angle greater than pi/4, then it will no longer be weakly octahedral. Simply take a plane P through the origin containing the original vector x. Then there are vectors y and z in P with an angle of pi/2 + epsilon between them for some small epsilon. The set S' = {x,y,z} is not octahedral, and therefore S is not weakly octahedral.

Comment: I agree there are problems with my suggestion. I do not see how to fix them.

Comment: Does anyone (Geometers, Combinatorialists) have any intuition about whether the statement should be true?

Comment: I'd intersect your lines with the unit sphere. Then a shape would be octahedral if it fits inside the all-right-angles spherical triangle, and would be weakly octahedral if its diameter is no more than $\frac\pi2$. So you'd be asking whether there is only one way to partition the sphere into $8$ partitions, each of which has diameter no more than $\frac\pi2$, and with antipodal symmetry for the whole setup. Not sure whether that view makes anything easier, but it might be useful. I'd assume the strongly octahedral solution to be the only one, but I don't have a proof.